# Encrypt hash map keys while keeping constant lookup speed

Tags: file, security, encryption, cryptography

I would like to encrypt the keys and values of a hash map with AES256 CBC, individually.
The challenge is to encrypt the keys while maintaining the constant lookup speed and security (mainly against dictionary attacks).

I read about blind indices, but these need some randomness at creation (salt, nonce) and it is impossible for the lookup function to recreate the nonce when searching. At lookup we would need to know where to fetch the nonce from for a particular key, which in the end would mean to be vulnerable elsewhere.

So far, I can only think of two options.

**First** one would be to just not encrypt keys, although I would prefer to do it.

The **second** one would be to obtain the blind indices by applying a transformation like

```
blind_index(key) = encrypt(digest(key))
```

but the problem here is that you need a unique initialisation vector for each key encryption, which brings us again to the problem described above: having a table of IVs used, in order for the lookup function to be able to reconstruct the blind index when searching, which is moving the same problem elsewhere.

For the second approach, my thought was: since I always encrypt unique values (keys are unique and even if they are substrings of one another, e.g. 'awesome' and 'awesome_key', they are hashed before encryption, so they look quite different in their 'hashed & unencrypted' form) I could use a global IV for all encryptions, which can be easily accessible to the lookup function. Since the lookup function requires the encryption key, only the owner will be able to compute the blind index correctly and in the map itself there will be no visible similarities between keys that are similar in plaintext.

The big problem I have with the second approach is that it violates the idea of never using IVs for more than one encryption. I could obfuscate the IV 'to make it more secure,' but that's again a bad idea since IVs are supposed to be plaintext.

More details about the circumstances:

- app for mobile
- map will be dumped to a file
- map will be accessible for lookup through a REST API

Maybe I should use a different algorithm (e.g. EBC)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is completely in the realm of Format Preserving Encryption (FPE). However, applying it is hard and libraries that handle it well are not distributed in every detergent package. If you may expand your ciphertext compared to the plaintext then you could also look at SIV modes, which are easier to handle (wrap your byte array and provide a fast `hashCode` yourself). By the way, for these kind of protocol / use case related questions, I'd prefer security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you, I'll check your suggestions out. As for the future, I'll use security.stackexchange.com for these kind of questions, as you said.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes After reading the Wikipedia article about it, I tend to believe that FPE is something I could indeed use. I will also check SIVs out, but overall I think these two are the right solutions, so I would happily accept this as an answer if you would post it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely in the realm of Format Preserving Encryption (FPE). However, applying it is hard and libraries that handle it well are not all that common. FPE takes a an amount of bits or even a range and then returns an encrypted value of the same size or in the same range. This ciphertext is pseudo-random in the given domain as long as the input values are unique (which, for keys in a hash table, they are by definition).

If you may expand your ciphertext compared to the plaintext then you could also look at SIV modes (AES-SIV or AES-GCM_SIV, which are much easier to handle. These return a byte array, which could turn into a `String`, e.g. by using base64 encoding. Otherwise you could wrap the byte array and provide your own `equals` and `hashCode` method. Note that these expand your plaintext relatively significantly; these are authenticated modes. Advantage: the IV gets calculated from the input and any change in the input will randomize the ciphertext again.

Finally, you could of course simply use an IV or nonce to produce your ciphertext and prefix it to the value. However, beware that reencryption of changed values using the same IV would be rather dangerous, as you may leak information through repetition. In some modes this could entirely break the confidentiality offered. So you would have to prevent reuse of the IV.

The use of ECB is certainly not recommended for strings. A single block encrypt would work of course if the input is (or can be expanded to) a single block.

Comment: Comprehensive FPE implementations can be found [here](https://github.com/topics/format-preserving-encryption)